# Ethereum token sale api

Tags: explorer-api

I was curious, and well am not a developer.

However I was wondering if someone could provide the code to create the /ethereum sent to an ico contract addresss/ API from etherscan.

Dcorp and several other ico's have used it, to keep track or their ico's success.
https://www.dcorp.it/crowdsale

I figure in the coding I would be able to change the contract address so I could monitor ico's as sort of a precursor to see whats hot though.

Comment: [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis) does provide a developer API, you should be able to implement such functionality on top of it.